# Why my Mongo database is not responding in my first request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For contextualization, I am doing it using NodeJS and Mongoose, and I have two models in my mongo database: User and Product.

I am trying to update my user in these two models (a user has many products and a product has one owner {user})
But when I call the request, it only updates the user model, and the product model keeps showing the old user info.

Here is the code:

```
//USER CONTROLLER//
 static async ChangeUser(req, res) {
    
    const {name, password, email, location} = req.body

    const changesToDo = {
        name, 
        password,
        email,
        location
    }

    const user = await UserBusiness.GetUserByToken(req)
    if (user.status) {
        res.status(user.status).json({message: user.msg})
    }

    const changedUser = await UserBusiness.ChangesToDo(changesToDo, user)
    if (changedUser.status) {
        res.status(changedUser.status).json({message: changedUser.msg})
    }

    return res.status(200).json({message: "Alterações concluídas", user: changedUser})
}

//USER BUSINESS//

static async ChangesToDo(changes, user) {

    if (!changes.name || changes.name.trim() == "") {
        changes.name = user.name
    }
    if (await this.UserExists(changes.email)) {
        return new EndMsg(400, "Email já está em uso")
    }
    if (!changes.email || changes.email.trim() == "") {
        changes.email = user.email
    }

    const pwdCompare = await bcrypt.compare(changes.password, user.password)

    if (pwdCompare || !changes.password || changes.password.trim() == "") {
        changes.password = user.password
    } else {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(12)
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(changes.password, salt)
        changes.password = hash
    }
    if (!changes.location || changes.location.trim() == "") {
        changes.location = user.location
    }

    const updateUser = await UserRepository.UpdateUser(changes, user)
    if (updateUser.status) {
        return new EndMsg(updateUser.status, updateUser.msg)
    }
    return updateUser
}

  
   ///USER REPOSITORY///
   static async UpdateUser(changes, user) {

    try {
        const update = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {name: changes.name, password: changes.password, email: changes.email, location: user.location})                      
        if (!update) {
            return new EndMsg(400, "Nao foi possível alterar os dados")
        }

        const otherUpdates = await Product.updateMany({'owner._id': user._id}, {owner: user})

        
        console.log(otherUpdates)
        return update
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return new EndMsg(500, err)
    }
}

///USER MODEL///

const mongoose = require('../db/coon')
const Product = require('../models/Product')

const { Schema } = mongoose

const User = mongoose.model(
    'User',
    new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        wishList: [{
            type: Object
        }],
        location: {
            type: String
        },

        product: Object
    },
    {timestamps: true}
    ),
)

module.exports = User



///PRODUCT MODEL///
const mongoose = require('../db/coon')

const { Schema } = mongoose

const Product = mongoose.model(
    'Product',
    new Schema({
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number
        },
        secao: [{
            type: Object
        }],
        owner:{
            type: Object
        }
    })
)

module.exports = Product
```

Note: I am not receiving any error messages and it really updates. But only when I call the request for the second time.

Comment: In `UpdateUser` function, have you ever logged `user`, `update` and `otherUpdates`? Please show me.

Comment: When i console.log the returns, it really returns the new value, but it does not load this data in DataBase. And just to assure this, i am handling theese kinds of exception.

Comment: Can you post `User` and `Product` model declarations?

Comment: Of course. I have made the edits already, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the user object retrieved from the database to the UpdateUser function in the UserRepository so to fix this issue you need to pass the changes object instead, which contains the updated user information

```
const otherUpdates = await Product.updateMany({'owner._id': user._id},{owner: changes });
```

Comment: Perfect!! It worked. Thank you very much, i really wasn't seeing this little problem haha